# Time of Day in the JSON response model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, iso8601

I am using ASP.NET Web Api 2 with Json.NET 6.0.1.

According to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), dates should be interchanged in a certain way.  I am using the `IsoDateTimeConverter()` in order to achieve this:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());
```

**But how should "time of day" be returned in a JSON response model?**

I cannot find anything for this in the ISO specification.

Should time perhaps be returned as a:

- `TimeSpan`? (with expectation of the user to not use this as a duration representation)
- `DateTime`? (with expectation of the user to drop off the date part)
- A custom `Time` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard structure in JSON for containing dates or times (see [JSON.org](http://json.org/)).  The de-facto stardard for dates-time values is using a string in ISO 8601 format, as you mentioned.  But since there is no official standard it really comes down to what works best for you and consumers of your API.

Using a `DateTime` object is a reasonable choice because the support already exists in Json.Net and other serializers for converting these to and from ISO 8601 strings.  So this would be the easiest to implement.  However, users of your API would have to know to disregard the date portion, as you said.  You could set the date to 0001-01-01 to emphasize its irrelevance.  This isn't so different from the more common situation where you need only a date in your API and the time doesn't matter.  Most people just set the time to midnight in this case and let it go.  But, I would agree that this approach does seem to have a little bit of a "code smell" to it, given that part of the value is just noise.

Perhaps a cleaner idea is to format your `DateTime` value as ISO 8601, but then chop off the date portion before returning it.  So users of the API would get a string that looks like `14:35:28.906Z`.  You could write a simple `JsonConverter` to handle this for you during serialization.  This would sort of give you the best of both worlds -- a cleaner API, but you still can work with the familiar `DateTime` struct internally.

A custom `Time` class could also work here, but might be overkill, depending.  If you do need to go there, you might want to look into a third-party library such as [Noda Time](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/), which has classes already built for these kinds of things, and also has pre-built converters for Json.Net.

I would definitely not choose `TimeSpan` for this purpose.  Wrong tool for the job.